# How to get object from WebClient bodyToMono or toEntity in a Non-Blocking way

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am new to Spring WebClient.  I have the following method calling an endpoint using WebClient and I need to return  ResponseEntity from this method. I know that I can call `block()`, but is there anyway I can do it in a non-blocking way? Even if I can return `Mono`, the calling method will still need to unwrap it and get the ResponseEntity, how does the calling method do, call the `block`?

```
public ResponseEntity getData() {

    Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> entityMono = webClient.post()
                                                       .uri(url)
                                                       .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(aString))
                                                       .retrieve()
                                                       .toEntity(String.class);

     // what do I need to do here so that I can return ResponseEntity non-blocking

}
```

Comment: Just return the `Mono`. Immediately you unwrap it you’re blocking.

Comment: if return `Mono`, how does the calling method unwrap it?

Comment: It doesn’t. It handles it asynchronously by either calling a processor on it (`map`, etc) or - at the end of the pipeline - calling `subscribe()`. In many cases - for example returning a response to the user in the case of a REST API or doing something with a database - you pass the reactive construct into the framework (webflux, r2dbc etc) and it handles subscription.

Comment: The ResponseEntity returned from the webclient contains a token that will be used in the second webclient call. so are you saying that the calling method should call `map` or `subscribe` to use the token inside `map` or `subscribe`?  Also, `map` is also blocking, right?

Comment: I think you need to do some reading; your questions show that you don’t really know what reactive _is_. No `map` is **not** blocking as it returns another reactive construct. https://projectreactor.io/learn

Comment: yes, i am new to the topic

Comment: https://www.manning.com/books/spring-in-action-sixth-edition is good reading and has a complete part focused on Spring WebFlux. Consider reading it ;)

Comment: Thank you! @JoãoDias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to return a `ResponseEntity` there is no other way, you need to `block`.

Think of it this way, you do a request, you need to wait for the response until we can construct a `ResponseEntity` because we need the returned data until we can build it.

If you are writing a fully non-blocking application, this is bad, since in the middle of everything you are basically yelling STOP, and the entire application freezes until it gets the response and then continues.

The other option is to return a `Mono<ResponseEntity>` which is more like a promise. You are basically saying that "when i get the answer back, i will promise that there will be a ResponseEntity, i just dont know when so you will have to do with the Mono for now`

Then after that you can extract, transform, using functions like, map, flatMap, zip, etc. etc but as long as you always return a `Mono` because remember, we dont have the value, we are basically just building a pipeline of what we want our application to do when we actually have the value.

i suggest you go through the [Reactor Documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#intro-reactive) to understand what problem reactive programming solves, and then how to get started with it as it is way too much to explain in a simple answer on stack overflow.